# Excited states of a conformal field theory

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory, path-integral, quantum-states

Consider the Euclidean path integral defining the vacuum state of a conformal field theory.

Why does the addition of sources for scalar primary or stress tensor operators to the Euclidean path integral give us the CFT excited states?

Comment: are you perhaps referring to the [state-operator correspondence](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146594)?

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform: This is exactly what I mean.