# Why is the limiting operator in the CFT state-operator correspondence well-defined, and why is conformal symmetry necessary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

Consider a Euclidean CFT in radial quantisation, and let $S$ be the unit sphere centred on the origin. The state-operator correspondence says that any state $\Psi_S$ living on $S$ can be prepared by a path integral with an insertion *only at the origin*. It is proved as follows (see Sec 4.6 in [Tong](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html)):

Let $S_r$ be the sphere of radius $r$ centred on the origin. Then we can evolve the state $\Psi_S$ radially to get some state $\Psi_r$ living on $S_r$. This evolution can be written as a path integral on the annulus $r\leq |\mathbf{x}|\leq 1$:
\begin{align}
\tag{1}\Psi_S[\phi_S] &=  \int D\phi_{r} \space\Psi_r[\phi_r] \int_{\phi|_{S_r}=\phi_r}^{\phi|_S=\phi_S}D\phi e^{-S}   \\
\tag{2}&=\int_{\phi|_S = \phi_S} D\phi \space\space\Psi_{S_r}\big[\phi|_{S_r}\big]\space e^{-S}. 
\end{align}

(I'm working in the wavefunctional picture, where $\Psi_S$ is a functional of the field configuration $\phi_S$ on $S$, and likewise for $\Psi_r$. The second line follows since integrating over $\phi_r$ removes the inner boundary condition.)

Eq (2) tells us that any state $\Psi_S$ can be prepared by a path integral on the annulus $r\leq|\mathbf{x}|\leq 1$ with some appropriate insertion $\Psi_r[\phi|_{S_r}]$ on  the inner boundary.

Now take $r\to 0$, so the inner boundary shrinks to the origin. Hence we conclude that $\Psi_S$ can be prepared by an insertion at the origin.

**Question 1:** How exactly is the $r\to 0$ limit defined? Each $\Psi_r$ is a functional depending on $\phi|_{S_r}$, whereas in the $r\to 0$ limit we generally expect to obtain an insertion depending on not just $\phi(0)$ but also its derivatives. I think the existence of an appropriate limit is the exact content of what people call the "state-operator correspondence", but I can't find any reference addressing this.

**Question 2:** Why does the QFT need to be conformal for the above to work? Even without conformal symmetry, the path integral still defines *some* map from states on $S$ to states on $S_r$. Then we can take $r\to 0$ as before and the rest of the argument seems to work fine, showing that all states can be prepared by an insertion at the origin. In other words, I'm claiming that radial quantisation is perfectly well-defined in an arbitrary QFT. Unlike in CFT, in general the 1-parameter family of evolution maps from $S$ to $S_r$ will not be the exponential of some conserved charge, but I don't see why this would pose a problem to the above argument.

I'm asking these two questions together because I suspect their answers might be related. For example, perhaps the limiting procedure in the state-operator correspondence is well-defined precisely when the theory is conformal.

---

EDIT: another confusing point is that usually in QFT operators have to be smeared: they're not well-defined "at a point". So I don't know whether the state-operator correspondence is even well-defined, at least the way it's normally written.

Comment: Honestly I think the operator version of the derivation is clearer than the path integral one. I recommend seeing chapter 6 of the yellow book (Di Francesco), may help you out.

Comment: I just think about how a theory on a cylinder can easily have a state which oscillates as $t \to -\infty$ without reaching a limit. This is what the ability to sort states into dilation irreps buys you.

Comment: About question (2) here's one intuitive argument. In a standard QFT we also have in/out states defined at $t\to \pm \infty$. These states are created by creation/annihilation operators which can be written as integrals of quantum fields over the Cauchly slices at $t\to \pm \infty$. The point to observe then is that the state is really associated to the quantum field at infinitely many points. In a CFT you can use a conformal map to switch to radial quantization. This shrinks the surfaces $t\to \pm \infty$ to points and allows for the states to be associated to quantum fields at single points.

Comment: The point is that you start with the theory in one space, and then the fact that the fields have definite transformation properties under conformal maps, you are allowed to equally realize the theory in another space related to the first by a conformal map. This property is required to be able to use a conformal map to shrink $t\to \pm \infty$ to points, which occurs because of the Weyl factor $e^{t}$ in the map between $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and the cylinder $(0,\infty)\times S^{d-1}$.

Comment: I don't think these replies address my real concern in Question 2, which is that we ought to be able to do radial quantisation, and thus obtain a state-operator correspondence, in an arbitrary QFT. I've edited that part of the my question to put more emphasis on this point.

Comment: We ought to be able to do it for the subset of states $\Psi_r$ such that the limit as $r \to 0$ exists right?

Comment: Right. So my question is: why does that limit exist for *all* states in a CFT, but only *some* states in an arbitrary QFT?

Comment: Something which many sources gloss over is that this limit fails to exist for many states in a CFT as well. But it does exist for dilation eigenstates so we can decompose more general states in terms of those. It's about the set of states created by a local operator *spanning* the Hilbert space rather than being equal to it.

Comment: The set of states created by insertions at the origin is a vector space: if inserting $\mathcal{O}_1$ creates state $|\mathcal{O}_1\rangle$ and inserting $\mathcal{O}_2$ creates $|\mathcal{O}_2\rangle$, then inserting $\mathcal{O}_1+\mathcal{O}_2$ creates $|\mathcal{O}_1\rangle + |\mathcal{O}_2\rangle$. So your last comment is incorrect.

Comment: The "CFT states not created by a local operator" (and therefore the ones that could make one feel better about general QFTs not having a state-operator map) are often said to have the form $\left | \psi \right > = \int dx f(x) \mathcal{O}(x) \left | 0 \right >$. But I don't have a good answer for why people who happily consider these "continuous linear combinations" at the level of states should not instead do this to operators first and then act on the vacuum once. It must be more singular in some sense.

Comment: Hi nodumbquestions. Is eq. (1) from a reference?

Comment: See bottom equation on p102 of [Tong](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html). I simplified his expression using the fact that integrating over fields with fixed boundary condition and then integrating over that boundary condition is the same as just integrating over all fields. I'll add a line in my question to clarify this step.

Comment: Doesn't something have to exist before you can smear it? Your usage of "not well defined" is not well defined.

Comment: Quantum fields are operator-valued distributions (i.e. they take a smooth function and give an operator), not operator valued functions on spacetime. So generally in QFT there is no operator called "$\phi(x)$". Sorry if I was sloppy before, but to be fair it's very standard to say "$\phi(x)$ must be smeared to be a well-defined operator".

Comment: Ok good. Is the question mainly about adding rigour now? Or is there also an intuitive objection to using the transformation law of a conformal primary to argue that the $r \to 0$ limit exists when it otherwise wouldn't?

Comment: What is the argument you refer to? It might be useful if you submitted it as an answer. Currently I'm not even sure what the correct definition of "limit" is here, and what it means to be an operator at a point (e.g. how do you insert $\partial_\mu \phi(0)$ into the path integral, given the domain of the path integral contains non-differentiable functions?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that any state on the sphere can be prepared by a local operator at the origin. For example, take the state $|\Psi\rangle=\phi(x)\phi(-x)|0\rangle$, defined on the unit sphere, where $0<|x|<1$ and $\phi$ is some local scalar operator. If it were true that $|\Psi\rangle=\mathcal{O}(0)|0\rangle$ for some local operator $\mathcal{O}$, then the correlation function $\langle 0|\mathcal{O}'(y)|\Psi\rangle$, where $\mathcal{O}'$ is a local operator, would be regular for all $|y|>0$ (the defintion $\langle 0|\mathcal{O}'(y)|\Psi\rangle$ makes sense only for $|y|>1$ but since correlation functions are analytic, this is enough to ask questions also at |y|<1). But of course we know that $\langle 0|\mathcal{O}'(y)|\Psi\rangle=\langle 0|\mathcal{O}'(y)\phi(x)\phi(-x)|0\rangle$ has singularities at $y=\pm x$ and no singularity at $y=0$.

As Connor Behan points out in the comments only the dilatation eigenstates can be represented by local operators at a point. For dilatation eigenstates, there is no limit to be taken as they evolve trivially. To make the argument precise, one needs to define what you mean by a local operator.

The objection raised by the OP to Connor Behan's comment is addressed by the following observation. The dilatation eigenstates do not span the Hilbert space, they only span a dense subset. In other words, to reproduce a completely general state, one needs to take infinite sums of dilatation eigenstates. These sums will converge in the Hilbert space, but not in the space of local operators (by the argument in the beginning of this answer).

Comment: The OPE is usually written in terms of operators (it is an "operator" expansion, after all). E.g. we'd usually write $\phi(x)\phi(-x)=\sum_k c_k(x,\partial) \hat{\mathcal{O}}_k(y)\big|_{y=0}$. Are you saying that this is wrong, since the RHS doesn't converge, and that it only becomes correct when we have both sides acting on the vacuum?

Comment: @nodumbquestions To start, you would need to define what you mean by "operator" -- this is a massively over-used term -- and what topology you have in mind on the space of "opeators". But yes, it is a well-known fact that the OPE is only guaranteed to converge when acting on the vacuum state, in which case it is a convergence in the Hilbert space. It is important to note, however, that there is a freedom in the choice of quantization, and what doesn't act on the vacuum state in one quantization may act on the vacuum state in another quantization.

Comment: A simple example is arranging 4 operators on a line in the order 1,2,3,4 and trying to take the OPE between 1 and 3 in the four-point function. It will not converge.

Comment: Ok, this is definitely the closest I've come to understanding an issue which has bothered me for a while - your answers are appreciated. Sadly all resources I've seen are quite sloppy, so I can't tell precisely what the State-Operator Correspondence and the OPE are supposed to mean. Do you know a text which treats these things in a way that makes sense?

Comment: i.e. when you say "it is a well-known fact", a citation would be useful.

Comment: @nodumbquestions a standard reference is "Convergence of operator product expansions on the vacuum in conformal invariant quantum field theory" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01609130

Comment: @nodumbquestions This reference is in working in Lorentzian signature, but the difference is superficial. The avatar of this in Euclidean signature is that the OPE between two operators converges if you can separate them from the other operators in the correlator by a sphere. This just means that there is a radial quantization in which both operators act on the vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: OP's wave functional eqs. (1/2) relies on a sewing axiom/completeness relation, not a limit per se.

1. *Review.* In a (not necessarily conformal) QFT the wave functional is
   $$ \Psi(\phi,t)~=~{}_H\langle \phi,t|\Psi\rangle_H ~=~{}_H\langle \phi,0|\Psi(t)\rangle_S\tag{A}$$
   where the instantaneous Heisenberg eigenstates
   $$ \hat{\Phi}({\bf r},t)|\phi,t \rangle_H ~=~\phi({\bf r})|\phi,t \rangle_H \tag{B}$$
   satisfy a completeness relation
   $$ \int\!{\cal D}\phi~|\phi,t \rangle_H {}_H\langle \phi,t|~=~{\bf 1} \tag{C}$$
   and orthonormality relation
   $$ {}_H\langle \phi_1,t|\phi_2,t \rangle_H~=~\prod_{\bf r}\delta(\phi_1({\bf r})\!-\!\phi_2({\bf r})). \tag{D}$$
   The overlap/kernel is given by the path integral
   $$\begin{align}K(\phi_f,t_f;\phi_i,t_i)
   ~=~&{}_H\langle \phi_f,t_f|\phi_i,t_i \rangle_H \cr
   ~=~&\int_{\Phi|_{\partial B(0,t_i)}=\phi_i}^{\Phi|_{\partial B(0,t_f)}=\phi_f}\!
   \left[ \prod_{x\in B(0,t_f) \backslash B(0,t_i)} d\Phi(x)\right]~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]} \cr
   ~=~&\int_{\Phi(\cdot,t_i)=\phi_i}^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\!
   \left[\prod_{{\bf r},~t_i\leq t\leq t_f}d\Phi({\bf r},t)\right]~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]} \cr
   ~=~&\int_{\Phi(\cdot,t_i)=\phi_i}^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\!
   {\cal D}\Phi~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}.\end{align}\tag{E}$$
   OP's eq. (1) follows from eqs. (A), (C) & (E) without using conformal symmetry.
   $$\begin{align} \Psi(\phi_f,t_f)~\stackrel{(A)+(C)}{=}&\int\!{\cal D}\phi_i~ {}_H\langle \phi_f,t_f|\phi_i,t_i\rangle_H \Psi(\phi_i,t_i) \cr
   ~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~&\int\!{\cal D}\phi_i~\Psi(\phi_i,t_i)
   \int_{\Phi(\cdot,t_i)=\phi_i}^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\!
   {\cal D}\Phi~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}. 
    \end{align}\tag{1}$$
2. Now let us consider a [CFT](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conformal+field+theory). A wave functional $\Psi_{\cal O}(\phi_f,t_f)$ for a local operator $\hat{\cal O}$, or corresponding state
   $$|{\cal O}\rangle_H~=~\hat{\cal O}(0)| \Omega \rangle_H,\tag{83}$$
   is given by
   $$\begin{align}\Psi_{\cal O}(\phi_f,t_f)
   ~=~&{}_H\langle \phi_f,t_f|{\cal O} \rangle_H \cr
   ~\stackrel{(83)}{=}~&{}_H\langle \phi_f,t_f|\hat{\cal O}(0)|\Omega\rangle_H \cr
   ~\stackrel{(C)}{=}~&\int\!{\cal D}\phi_i~ {}_H\langle \phi_f,t_f|\phi_i,t_i\rangle_H \Psi_{\cal O}(\phi_i,t_i) \cr
   ~\stackrel{(E)}{=}~&\int\!{\cal D}\phi_i~\Psi_{\cal O}(\phi_i,t_i)
   \int_{\Phi(\cdot,t_i)=\phi_i}^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\!
   {\cal D}\Phi~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}\cr
   ~=~&\int^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\!
   \left[\prod_{{\bf r},~ t\leq t_f}d\Phi({\bf r},t)\right]~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}{\cal O}(0) \cr
   ~=~&\int^{\Phi(\cdot,t_f)=\phi_f}\! {\cal D}\Phi~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}{\cal O}(0),\end{align}\tag{F}$$
   due to a sewing axiom/completeness relation. In particular, the middle expressions/right-hand sides of eq. (F) are independent of $t_i$, so the limit-process $t_i\to -\infty$ is a constant process, and therefore convergent to that constant.

   An $n$-point correlator function satisfies
   $$\begin{align} {}_H\langle\Omega |T\left\{ \hat{\cal O}_1(x_1)\ldots \hat{\cal O}_n(x_n)
   \right\}|\Omega\rangle_H
   ~=~&\int\!{\cal D}\Phi~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]} {\cal O}_1(x_1)\ldots {\cal O}_n(x_n)\cr
   ~=~&\left[ \prod_{b=1}^n \int\!{\cal D}\phi_b~ {}_H\langle \phi_b,R_b |{\cal O}_b\rangle_H \right]\cr
   &\int_{\Phi|_{\partial B(x_b,R_b)}=\phi_b}\!
   \left[ \prod_{x\notin\cup_{b=1}^n B(x_b,R_b)} d\Phi(x)\right]~e^{-\frac{1}{\hbar}S[\Phi]}, \end{align}\tag{81}$$
   cf. Ref. 2.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146594/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664696/2451) related Phys.SE posts.

References:

1. D. Tong, [*Lectures on String Theory*](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html); Section 4.6.
2. D. Simmons-Duffin, *TASI Lectures on the Conformal Bootstrap,*
   [arXiv:1602.07982](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.07982); Chapter 6.

Comment: The logic here is unclear to me. I want to show that every state can be prepared by an insertion at the origin (equivalently, acting on the vacuum by some $\hat{O}(0)$). But you seem to be taking this as a starting point in Eq (83), and then using it to prove... what exactly? Note that my original question is basically how you got from the fourth to the fifth line of Eq (F), which requires taking a limit.